# Area Lights disappearing when rendering image

Tags: rendering, lighting

I'm quite new to blender and I was following a tutorial by Blender Guru on youtube. Everything looked alright in the render viewport but when I rendered the image, I discovered that some of my area lights disappeared. Not all my area lights, but the main light did. I tried delete the light and re-add it, but it's still the same problem: its only viewable in the the viewport and gone when I render.

Screenshots of viewport and render is attached.

Any advice will be greatly appreaciated!

Image in viewport
[image]

Image when rendered
[image]

The 2 marked ones are the missing lights, the yellow is my main light source
[image]

Comment: I would check to make sure all your layers you want are selected at the bottom. I would also check that the camera icon in the outliner is on (next to your lights) so it renders and then I would check your layers tab (next to the render tab) to make sure everything looks ok there.

Comment: if you want to upload your blend file I can take a look http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you so much, I found the missing lights were off in the  outliner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy without the scene of Blender, but I try to guess the problem, which I think can be solved by checking the outliner at the top left, looks, if the camera is active for rendering that light.

[image]

Comment: Yes thank you, this was what I was missing. My lights were off in the outliner.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it took some time before I found the issue.
My area lights did not show anywhere, no matter which viewport/render visibilities and light power values I used.

My area light had an x-value of 0, so basically the light only defines a line which apparently can't emit light.
So make sure that your area light values define a 2-dimensional area and not only a line or point.